# Add C code to a browser plugin

Tags: plugins, p2p

I made an UDP hole punching client using PJNATH library (C code). Is it possible to include this in a plugin to give the browser NAT traversal ability? (I want to make a p2p connection from browser to a non browser client)

Thanks

Comment: Plugins are written in C usually, so it should be possible, yes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Plugins

Comment: Do you know if there is something similar already implemented (PJNATH running on browser)?